# Benefits of x64 .Net applications

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit

We have a few in house applications written in visual studio.net 2008 and a few written in 2010.

I'm upgrading to visual studio 2015, and plan on migrating all the apps over so everything is on the same version.

**So, the question:** Since all the computers are here are x64, should I build the apps for x64, or x86? I think there is a bit of a mix currently, and I'd like everything to be consistent.

I know memory addressing is a benefit of x64, but none of the inhouse programs are that memory intensive.
Are there any other benefits?

Answer (score 1):

> I know memory addressing is a benefit of x64, but none of the inhouse programs are that memory intensive.

Memory addressing is not strictly a benefit, but a mixed blessing.

You can address far more memory with x64.  However, your pointers are also twice as large.  x64 programs tend to use more memory for this reason.  If you do not need to address beyond what is available in a 32-bit process, stick with 32-bit.